# Heroku Slug Size Too Large

Tags: gradle, heroku

I tried to deploy my spring-boot project to Heroku but got an error due to the large slug size.

> Compiled slug size: 501.8M is too large (max is 500M).

Thus:

> Push failed --> Push rejected

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geRAH.png)

I have my front end as a git submodule using nodejs.
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCw1k.png) has tasks to run frontend (npm install, run, build) then copy build to static folder to serve with spring boot

I executed `git push heroku main:master` to push codes to Heroku master and looks like Heroku recognized my submodule, cloned it, successfully built the front end, and performed the tasks.

What I already tried and did not work:

1. Build Cache:

- `heroku plugins:install heroku-builds`
- `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`

2. Buildpacks: error `App not compatible with buildpack:`

- https://github.com/SectorLabs/heroku-buildpack-git-submodule.git
- https://github.com/Lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean

3. Check my /app with `heroku run bash -a top-data` --> `~ $ du -sh` gives
   `4.0K   .` and nothing else in it
4. Docker Image was deployed successfully but the app showed nothing probably because of the submodule.
5. `.slugignore` is added but there is not much I can add to it since I have added many to `.gitignore` including node_modules. I run `du -sh * | sort -rn` in my root project: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlCdf.png)

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!